# Reaching nonvoid Function [C]

Tags: c

This is currently my code:

```
if (f(mid >=0){
if (f(mid)<=tolerance){
return mid;
} else if (f(mid)>lo){
bisection ((*f), lo, mid, tolerance);
} else {
return bisection ((*f), mid, hi, tolerance);
} else {
mid = (-1) * mid;
if (f(mid) <= tolerance) {
return mid;
} else if (f(mid)> lo){
bisection ((*f), lo, mid, tolerance);
} else {
return bisection ((*f), mid, hi, tolerance);
}
```

Just wondering where I might have messed up here, I've been stuck on this for a few hours

Comment: try `return bisection(...)`

Comment: Your function is supposed to return a `double` but you do not actually `return` any value.

Comment: Reaching ***the end of a*** non-void function.

Comment: That helped! I'm getting the wrong number, but this definitely helped. Thank you

Comment: Your comparison, `f(mid) > lo` doesn't make any sense. You should be checking whether `f(mid)` has the same sign as `f(hi`) or the same sign as `f(lo`).

Comment: please show the full code

Comment: No, that isn't your code. That is at best a subset of your code. Ideally, we should see a [mcve] (please follow that link), but at the very least we need to see the entirety of your function definition. (I'm guessing this is a recursive function called `bisection`.) The code is very difficult to read without proper indentation. When I indent it, I see `if` ... `else if`... `else` ... `else` -- the double `else` should have given you a syntax error. Please include at least the full function definition *and* copy-and-paste the exact error message(s) you get from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You only return from the `if` part of your if else list. You should return the result of your recursive calls with:

```
} else if (f(mid) > lo) {
    return bisection ((*f), lo, mid, tolerance);
} else {
    return bisection ((*f), mid, hi, tolerance);
}
```

Comment: And there are two syntax errors in the second bisection call... that's what you get for cut'n'pasting code :-)